# Как использовать гем rails-settings-cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems

Всем привет. Кто-нибудь пользовался гемом rails-settings-cached (https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-se...er/README.md)?

У меня по этому поводу следующие вопросы и проблемы. (все вопросы основываются на гайде по гему, ссылка выше)

1. У меня Rails v.4.2.1. какую версию гема мне нужно использовать "rails-settings-cached", "0.4.1" для Rails 4.1.x или "rails-settings-cached", "0.3.1" для Rails 4+ ??
2. После установки гема генерируем settings:

   $ rails g settings SettingsCompany

это создаст только модель settings_company.rb и миграцию для создания таблицы БД. Т.е. чтобы сделать вьюхи для редактирования настроек админом приложения, контроллер нужно вручную создать?

3. Опуская Вопрос 2, допустим я создаю контроллер для Settings. То, как я его назову, будет иметь значение?

Итак

```
rails g controller Settings
```

имеем (исходя из гайда):

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
 
  def index
    # to get all items for render list
    @settings = Setting.all
  end
 
  def edit
    @setting = Setting.unscoped.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

и при попытке перейти по settings/index.erb получается ошибка

> NameError in SettingsController#index uninitialized constant
>
> SettingsController::Setting

в строке

```
@settings = Setting.unscoped
```

и что такое и почему "unscoped"?

4. И я не совсем понимаю принцип работы гема

чтобы занести данные в БД никакие манипуляции с миграциями не нужны? и достаточно просто написать в коде что-то типа такого?:

```
Setting.admin_password = 'supersecret'
```

и это создаст в таблице запись со значениями

var = admin_password
value = supersecret

??

спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 "0.4.1" для Rails 4.1.x

2 Да, контроллер и вьюхи самостоятельно.

3 Должно быть так:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # to get all items for render list
    @settings = SettingsCompany.get_all 
  end
end
```

unscoped отменяет все scope. Скоупы это предопределенные фильтры для класса:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }
end
```

Таким образом, можно вызвать Shirt.red и получить коллекцию красных рубашек.
В гайде unscoped используется для отмены каких-то внутренних скоупов, которые наложены в самом геме.

4 Да, достаточно

```
Setting.admin_password = 'supersecret'
```

эта магия работает через method_missing

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!