# Отправка формы Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form, route, submit

Продолжая [тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440221/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BC-rails-settings-cached) работы с гемом [rails-settings-cached](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached/blob/master/README.md) есть вопросы, связанные с отправкой формы

### Выходные данные

1. Есть модель SettingsAboutCompany
   с двумя полями: var и value

скрипт:

```
SettingsAboutCompany.office_email  = ‘example@adress.ru’
```

в поля var и value записывает office_email и example@adress.ru соответственно:

[image: Model Setting]

2. Контроллер settings_about_company_controller.rb выглядит так (на основе гайда [rails-settings-cached](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached/blob/master/README.md) )

   ```
   class Admin::SettingsAboutCompanyController < ApplicationController
       def index
         @settings = SettingsAboutCompany.get_all  
       end

       def edit
         @setting = SettingsAboutCompany.find(params[:id])
       end

   end
   ```
3. B routes.rb написал (хотя не уверен, что мне нужен edit):

   ```
   resources :settings_about_company, only: [:index, :edit]
   ```
4. Вьюха index.html.haml:

   ```
   <-- начало index-->
   = label_tag '[office_email]', "E-Mail"
   = text_field_tag '[office_email]', SettingsAboutCompany.office_email

   = render 'form' 
   <-- конец index-->
   ```
5. Форма для index.html.haml  -  _form.html.haml :

   ```
   <-- начало _form -->
   = form_for SettingsAboutCompany.supp_email do  
   - SettingsAboutCompany.office_email  = ‘example@adress.ru’ 
   <-- конец _form -->
   ```

Результат:
[image: index.html.haml]

### Вопросы:

1. Как сделать, чтобы запись в БД сохранялась по нажатию кнопки:
   Форма для index.html.haml  -  _form.html.haml :

   ```
   <-- начало _form -->
     = form_for SettingsAboutCompany.office_email do |f|
       = f.label SettingsAboutCompany.office_email, "E-mail" 
       = f.text_field SettingsAboutCompany.office_email 
       = f.submit "Сохранить" 
   <-- конец _form -->
   ```

при нажатии на кнопку конечно получаю ошибку маршрутизации

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [POST] "/admin/settings_about_company"

2. Как сделать форму, чтобы по нажатию кнопки заносились значения во все поля:

   ```
    = form_for @settings do |f|
      = f.label '[office_email]', "E-mail" 
      = f.text_field '[office_email]', SettingsAboutCompany.office_email

      = f.label '[office_phone]', "Phone number" 
      = f.text_field '[office_phone]', SettingsAboutCompany.office_phone 

      = f.submit "Сохранить"
   ```

на строчку:

```
    = form_for @settings do |f|
```

получаю ошибку:

> NoMethodError at /admin/settings_about_company
>
> undefined method `model_name' for ..>

Спасибо

Comment: 1-я задача решается роутом `resources :settings_about_company, only: [:index, :edit, :update]`

Comment: @MAXOPKA спасибо!